# Is there a way to run survival analysis in R when you have more than one death per event?

Tags: r, survival

For example, I have a data frame consisting of columns ID, Genotype, Sex, time (days), event (deaths), for a number of Drosophila strains of both sexes, where deaths can be anywhere from 0 to 2, 3, etc. Apologies as this is probably a very simple solution, but most tutorials about survival analysis don't answer it and only use datasets where the event is either 0 or 1.
Have tried typical loading of data frame and packages (this part seems fine) and then assign survival object and plot with ggsurvplot.

Comment: You have an aggregated dataset. Expand it into an individual level dataset. Then run a standard survival analysis.  For example, if you a record with three deaths, convert this to three records, each with a single death event.. In fact, the way you describe your data, it sounds like you don’t have any censoring events. If so, you don’t really need survival analysis…

Comment: @Limey thanks! Any recommendations on how to do that?

Comment: Poisson regression might be able to handle that. Why don't you post a sample dataset? Tested code is more likely to be offered when we have an unambiguous example on which we might apply methods.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your survival data looks like this:

| ID | Genotype | Sex | time (days) | event (deaths) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Control_Vial1 | Control | F | 10 | 1 |
| Control_Vial2 | Control | M | 10 | 1 |

**Option 1: Use the `ggbulksurv` package** at https://github.com/qhuitan/ggbulksurv - I wrote it specifically for this scenario. `ggbulksurv::get_indiv_surv()` would do the trick.

In order to make your data work with this package, you have to add a column called `condition` which would reflect the sex. Your input data should look like this:

| condition | ID | Genotype | Sex | day | dead |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| control_F | Control_Vial1 | Control | F | 10 | 3 |
| control_M | Control_Vial2 | Control | M | 10 | 2 |

**Option 2: Manually code this using tidyr::uncount()**

I'm assuming you have no censored data (that is, no flies have escaped/ gone missing/ gotten stuck in food).

Renaming some columns for easy reference:

| ID | genotype | sex | day | dead |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Control_Vial1 | Control | F | 10 | 3 |
| Control_Vial2 | Control | M | 10 | 2 |

```r
sample_data <- read.csv("path-to-file.csv")

# Add a condition column
sample_data <- sample_data %>% 
                tidyr::unite("condition", genotype:sex, remove = FALSE)


## -- Calculate dead -- ##
  df_dead <- sample_data %>%
    # Select only dead column
    dplyr::group_by(condition) %>%
    # Uncount so that each row becomes an individual
    tidyr::uncount(dead) %>%
    # Add status = 1 (dead)
    dplyr::mutate(status = 1)
```

If you have censored data, use this code instead:

| ID | genotype | sex | day | dead | censored |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Control_Vial1 | Control | F | 10 | 3 | 2 |
| Control_Vial2 | Control | M | 10 | 2 | 5 |

```r
 ## -- Calculate dead -- ##
  df_dead <- sample_data %>%
    # Select only dead column
    dplyr::group_by(condition) %>%
    dplyr::select(-c(censored)) %>%
    # Uncount so that each row becomes an individual
    tidyr::uncount(dead) %>%
    # Add status = 1 (dead)
    dplyr::mutate(status = 1)

  ## -- Calculate censored -- ##
  df_censored <- sample_data %>%
    # Select only censored column
    dplyr::group_by(condition) %>%
    dplyr::select(-c(dead)) %>%
    # Uncount so that each row becomes an individual
    tidyr::uncount(censored) %>%
    # Add status = 0 (censored)
    dplyr::mutate(status = 0)

  ## -- Combine -- ##
  df_combined <- dplyr::full_join(df_censored, df_dead,
                           join_by("condition", "day", "status")) %>%
    dplyr::arrange(day) %>%
    dplyr::ungroup()
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding the data set into one row per individual, as suggested in a comment and in another answer, is a very good choice in this situation and should be both reliable and extensible to more complicated situations.

For reference, it's also possible to use the `weights` argument to the R `coxph()` function to accomplish this. According to the help page:

> Case weights are treated as replication weights, i.e., a case weight of 2 is equivalent to having 2 copies of that subject's observation.

In your situation, you would have an event marker of 1 for death at a particular time and set of covariate values in a data row, but specify the number of individuals having the event and that set of covariate values as the weight value in that row. You could similarly use the `weights` argument, with an event marker of 0, for the number of flies that survived to the final observation time, for each set of covariate values.